# Reading encrypted excel file from dropbox into python

Tags: python, pandas, dropbox, xlwings

I'm looking to read a password-protected excel file directly from Dropbox into pandas. I don't want to download the file locally for data security reasons.

After poking around stackoverflow, I've found that I can easily read an password-protected excel file into pandas, e.g.,:

```
import xlwings
import pandas as pd

file = '../data/myfile.xlsx'
wb = xlwings.Book(file) #this opens excel locally and asks me to type in password
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet0']
excel_data = sheet.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame, header = False, expand='table').value
```

Alternatively, I can easily read in a normal excel file from dropbox into pandas, e.g.,:

```
import pandas as pd
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_token)
metadata, f = dbx.files_download('MYFOLDER/data/myfile.xlsx')
excel_data = pd.read_excel(f.content)
```

Is there any way I can combine these methods? So far, I've tried stitching them together where it would seem logical, but no luck! Or is there another method I can do that doesn't require me to first download the excel file onto my machine?

Comment: In what ways can you access the data using the dropbox library? Have you checked the xlwings docs, too?

Comment: To be fair, I haven't worked my way through all the documentation for _xlwings_. But my understanding is that with _dropbox_ you can use `files_download()` which allows you to read in the file to python by handling the "response" from dropbox (i.e., the file content), or you can use `files_download_to_file()` in which you download the file onto your computer.

Comment: _But my understanding is that with dropbox you can use files_download() which allows you to read in the file to python by handling the "response" from dropbox (i.e., the file content)_ In what format? Can that format be fed to xlwings? To be clear, you must use xlwings, or could something like openpyxl be sufficient?